# Is it possible to predict stack overflow?

Tags: rust, stack-overflow

I have a Rust program that uses recursion. Sometimes it hits "stack overflow" runtime error. I want to prevent this from happening. Instead, I want to have something like this inside my recursive function:

```
fn foo() -> u32 {
  if stack_is_almost_full() {
    panic!("Something is wrong with the recursion!");
  }
  // continue normally
}
```

Is it possible?

Comment: The context reads a little strange. Does it really depend on your remaining stack size if "Something is wrong with recursion"? And if you double your stack size - something with your recursion is ok, suddenly?

Comment: I want to throw a custom error message when there is a problem

Comment: Yes. But usually I see something like define a max. recursion depth for detecting such things instead of looking how much stack is left.

Comment: How would you recommend checking max recursion depth?

Comment: Yes, I'm fairly confident to say rust tag of stack overflow will receive many question today so yes we can predict stack overflow.

Comment: To state the obvious, you can also re-implment your solution iteratively, which usually involves a queue on the heap. That's the recommended solution when working with untrusted data that may be arbitrarily nested.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get an estimate for the remaining stack space from [`stacker::remaining_stack`](https://docs.rs/stacker/0.1.15/stacker/fn.remaining_stack.html).

But for detecting problems with recursion some more direct approach might be more appropriate:

```rust
const MAX_DEPTH: usize = 1024;
#[inline(always)]
fn foo() -> u32 {
    foo_rec(0).expect("MAX_DEPTH reached while recursing")
}

fn foo_rec(depth: usize) -> Option<u32> {
    if depth > MAX_DEPTH {
        None
    }
    // do your work possibly recursing, finally return something
    if should_recurse() {
        foo_rec(depth + 1)
    } else {
        Some(42)
    }
}

fn should_recurse() -> bool {
    true // uh-oh
}
```